# r quanteda error predict.textmodel_NB_fitted : not implemented

Tags: r, predict, quanteda

I'm trying to predict sentiment analysis from quanteda NB with this code :

```
library(quanteda)
X_train <-c( "I love this sandwich.",
             "This is an amazing place!",
             "I feel very good about these beers.",
             "This is my best work.",
             "What an awesome view",
             "I do not like this restaurant",
             "I am tired of this stuff.",
             "I can't deal with this",
             "He is my sworn enemy!",
             "this guy is horrible.")

Y_train <- c( 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)

Y_train <- c( 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
X_test <- c( "The beer was good.",
             "I do not enjoy my job",
             "I ain't feeling dandy today.",
             "I feel amazing!   pos",
             "Gary is a friend of mine.",
             "I can't believ I'm doing this.",
             "very sad about Iran",
             "You're the only one who can see this cause no one else is following me this is for you because you're pretty awesome",
             "ok thats it you win.",
             "My horsie is moving on Saturday morning.",
             "times by like a million",
             "but i'm proud.",
             "i want a hug)")
Y_test <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1) 
dfm_mat <- dfm( X_train)
tfidf_mat <- tfidf( dfm_mat, normalize = TRUE)
model <- textmodel_NB( tfidf_mat, Y_train, distribution = "multinomial")

predict( model, X_test)
```

And I got the following error message :

```
Error in newdata %*% t(log(object$PwGc)) : not-yet-implemented method for <character> %*% <dgeMatrix>
5.stop(gettextf("not-yet-implemented method for <%s> %%*%% <%s>", class(x), class(y)), domain = NA)
4.newdata %*% t(log(object$PwGc))
3.newdata %*% t(log(object$PwGc))
2.predict.textmodel_NB_fitted(model, X_test)
1.predict(model, X_test)
```

Running :
quanteda_0.9.8.5
Matrix_1.2-7.1
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.10

Anyone got any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are trying to predict the fitted Naives Bayes model from a character vector, which (as the error message states, although admittedly not in the clearest fashion) is not defined for a character vectors.

The solution is to predict your model on a dfm object, but one whose features have been matched to the training dfm.

```
# this creates a test dfm, and matches its features to the training dfm
dfm_test <- dfm_select(dfm(X_test), dfm_mat) 
## found 15 features from 36 supplied types in a dfm, padding 0s for another 21
```

Then the `predict()` method works fine:

```
predict(model, dfm_test)
## Predicted textmodel of type: Naive Bayes
## 
##              lp(1)       lp(0)     Pr(1)  Pr(0) Predicted
## text1   -4.2419639  -4.3728368    0.5327 0.4673         1
## text2  -15.1799166 -14.8238632    0.4119 0.5881         0
## text3   -4.2637198  -4.2239433    0.4901 0.5099         0
## text4  -11.3125631 -11.5833225    0.5673 0.4327         1
## text5   -7.9101340  -7.7336472    0.4560 0.5440         0
## text6  -11.5324821 -11.2864767    0.4388 0.5612         0
## text7   -7.7907806  -8.0525264    0.5651 0.4349         1
## text8  -18.3944576 -18.5330895    0.5346 0.4654         1
## text9   -0.6931472  -0.6931472    0.5000 0.5000         1
## text10  -7.7792864  -7.7569503    0.4944 0.5056         0
## text11  -4.3754953  -4.2186861    0.4609 0.5391         0
## text12  -0.6931472  -0.6931472    0.5000 0.5000         1
## text13  -4.2637198  -4.2239433    0.4901 0.5099         0
```

Comment: Thx a lot Ken. It seems obvious when I have the solution :)